# Display product list with custom taxonomy using shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I want to display a list of products and filtered by my custom taxonomy.
[This are the taxonomies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5vgo.png)

I think this code is not working. Thanks for helping.

```
[products columns="5" taxonomy="area" per_page="10" orderby="id" order="ASC" category="voucher"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the woocommerce documentation, there is no attribute "taxonomy" for this shortcode. 
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#section-6

I think that you're a little confused with tags and categories. 
In your case I would only use categories and subcategories to get the desired products.

Try this one (I'm asuming here, that area is a category and not a tag):

```
[products columns="5" limit="10" orderby="id" order="ASC" category="area"]
```

And use limit instead of per_page ;-)

Cheers, 
Dominik